# degree of intersections in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A standard exercise in basic algebraic geometry one sees is “Show that a hypersurface $X=V(f)$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ of degree $d$ meets a line $l=V(I)$ not contained in $X$ in
$d$ points, counted with multiplicity."  **My question is basically how I'm supposed to be defining the word "multiplicity."**

One can change coordinates to assume $I=(x_2,...,x_n)$, and then the homogeneous primes lying over $(f)+I$ correspond to elements of $V(\tilde f)\subset \mathbb{P}^1_k$ where $\tilde f$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $x_0,x_1$.  Such elements are just the maximal ideals generated by the irreducible factors of  $\tilde f$. Let $\mathfrak {m}=(g)\in \mathbb{P}^1_k$ be one such point and for the sake of clarity assume $\mathfrak {m} $ is a $k$ point, i.e. $g=ax_0-bx_1$ for $a,b\in k$ . Assume  $(ax_0-bx_1)^e ~||~\tilde f$.  Then clearly I want to say that $e$ is the multiplicity of the intersection of $l$ and $X$ at the point $\mathfrak {m}'\in \mathbb{P}^n_k$ corresponding to $\mathfrak {m}\in \mathbb{P}^1_k$. But $$\mathfrak {m}'= (g, x_2,...,x_n)$$ and if I stay in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, the only indication I have that this intersection has any kind of $e$-fold multiplicity is that $$I+(f)\subset (g^e, x_2,...,x_n)$$ which seems to me to be hideously coordinate and generator dependent.  At first I hoped $e$-fold multiplicity would mean something like that $$I+(f)\subset (\mathfrak {m}')^e$$ but obviously that's false. So I guess, am I thinking about multiplicity the right way?  It seems like it should be more coordinate invariant.  As it is, I don't even have a coherent definition -- what am I supposed to say, the intersection has $e$ fold multiplicity if you can raise one of the generators to the $e$ and still contain $I$ and $f$? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: there is an exercise (in Hartshorne, ex.I.5.3+4) that speaks of "multiplicity" and "intersection multiplicity" in an "elementary way" - for plane curves. Have you "generalized" this exercise to curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Thank you @hm2020 .  Yes thinking about $P^2$ is def a good idea. I will do that now.

Comment: I see, so it's not so obvious. it's strange because I've seen this exercise in multiple places where it's presented very early in the text and where no special care is taken to define multiplicity for the student, as if it's an obvious generalization of multiplicity of a linear factor of a polynomial. E.g. in Vakil it is exercise 8.2.E.  anyway, thank you again, @hm2020

Answer (score 1):

First, one should assume that $l$ is not contained in $f$. Next, view $l$ as a copy of $\Bbb P^1$: then the restriction of $f$ to $\Bbb P^1$ is a homogeneous degree-$d$ polynomial of two variables. Over an algebraically closed field, such a polynomial decomposes in to a product of $d$ homogeneous linear factors. These are the roots, and the fact that some of these factors may coincide is counting with multiplicity.

For example, in $\Bbb P^2$ if you consider $f=yz^2-x^3-x^2z$ and $l$ to be $V(x-y+z)$ with coordinates $x,z$, then the restriction of $f$ to $l$ is $(x+z)z^2-x^3-x^2z=(z-x)(x+z)^2$, which exactly matches the fact that the intersection of $l$ and $V(f)$ is $[1:2:1]$ and $[-1:0:1]$ where the second point of intersection is counted with multiplicity two because the two curves share a tangent there.

Comment: thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help! Is there a reason you've left that comment but neither upvoted nor accepted the answer?

Comment: @comity - the above explanation assumes $k$ is algebraically closed - your question does not make any assumptions on $k$ - you should include this assumption in your question.

Comment: I would upvote but im not able to upvote w my rep .  ill try to explain why I haven't accepted it tomorrow @HankScorpio

Comment: +1 (belatedly).